# Save multiple curl outputs and name file as current date/time

Tags: bash

I need to save the below curl outputs in a text file which is named as the current date + time.

```
btcusd=$(curl -s "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD" | egrep -o '"amount":"[0-9]+(\.)?([0-9]{0,7}")?' | sed 's/"amount"://' | sed 's/\"//g')
usdgbp=$(curl -s "https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?pairs=USDGBP&api_key=XXXXXX" | egrep -o '"price":[0-9]+(\.)?([0-9]{0,5})?' | sed 's/"price"://' | sed 's/\"//g')
```

The above outputs just the price of both btc/usd and usd/gbp, all unrequired data is already excluded.

Ideally when I run the bash script, a new txt file named 'ddmmyy-hhmmss.txt' would be created, with 2 lines of data, one for each price.

EG:

07/01/2019-115557.txt

> > 4017.89
> >
> > 0.7845

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just redirect the output to a file. First store the target file name in a variable. Then run your first command, redirecting its output to that file. Notice the single `>` which will overwrite whatever is in the file if it exists. The double `>>` appends the output of the command to an existing file.

```
FILE_NAME=`date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M%S"`.txt
curl -s "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD" | egrep -o '"amount":"[0-9]+(\.)?([0-9]{0,7}")?' | sed 's/"amount"://' | sed 's/\"//g' > $FILE_NAME
curl -s "https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?pairs=USDGBP&api_key=XXXXXX" | egrep -o '"price":[0-9]+(\.)?([0-9]{0,5})?' | sed 's/"price"://' | sed 's/\"//g' >> $FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The code looks ok. Btw, if the output of `https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?..` is in json, It's better (and way simpler) to use dedicated tools, like `jq`.